# How do I execute a function that returns a table and accepts a NVARCHAR

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I have a function that I would like to execute to see what it does:

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[DOCUVALUEUSERFILTERED] (@WINDOWSID NVARCHAR(255)) 
RETURNS TABLE AS 
    RETURN 
        SELECT * 
        FROM DOCUVALUEWITHUSERIDS 
        WHERE WINDOWSID = @WINDOWSID
```

I tried

```
Select * 
from [DOCUVALUEUSERFILTERED]('rigamonk')
```

but I get errors:

> Msg 313, Level 16, State 2, Line 1
>   An insufficient number of arguments were supplied for the procedure or function DBO.FIELDMASK.
>   Msg 4413, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Could not use view or function 'DOCUVALUEUSERFILTERED' because of binding errors.

Comment: You are using a different function than the one where you show the code

Comment: the function is called DOCUVALUEUSERFILTERED. i dont understand what you mean. the function is calling another function, is that what you mean?

Comment: This is the function that you posted: `ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[DOCUVALUEUSERFILTERED] (@WINDOWSID NVARCHAR(255))`, and this is how you are calling it: `Select * from DOCUFIELDUSERFILTERED('rigamonk')`. They are not the same function

Comment: Edited, sorry. Still cant call it. i get the same message

Comment: But the error message is about a `DBO.FIELDMASK` function

Comment: Well for one thing, you cannot call a user written function without prefixing the schema name (`[dbo].`) to it.

Comment: I sill get the fieldmask error: SELECT * FROM [dbo].[DOCUVALUEUSERFILTERED] WHERE WINDOWSID = 'rigamonk'

Comment: What is `DOCUVALUEWITHUSERIDS`?, did you post the whole code of the  `[DOCUVALUEUSERFILTERED]`?

Comment: Yes i did post the whole thing. i have no idea what DOCUVALUEWITHUSERIDS is. its not a table, its a view

Comment: Well don't code against objects that you don't know what they are. Perhaps it is a user function as well and needs one or more parameters.

Answer (score 0):

I would bet that DOCUVALUEWITHUSERIDS is a function as well and that it has required parameters.

try running just the select outside of the function

```
select top 1 * from DOCUVALUEWITHUSERIDS
```

If you get an error then you need to know more about how DOCUVALUEWITHUSERIDS works.